# In SQLAlchemy, how do I retry inserting a unique ID on conflict?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to insert a short 6 digit unique alpha-numeric ID in the database. I want to manage conflicts and try again in the same transaction. The chances of conflict are pretty low, but let's assume `n=1` for the sake of the argument. I've tried the following:

#### Code

```py
max_retries=3
bar = Bar()
db.session.add(bar)
db.session.flush()
while True:
    try:
        obj = Foo(foo=get_unique_id(n=6), bar_id=bar.id)
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.flush()
    except IntegrityError:
        db.session.rollback()
        max_retries -= 1
        if max_retries < 1:
            raise
    else:
        break
db.session.commit()
```

#### Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) insert or update on table "foo" violates foreign key constraint "foo_bar_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (bar_id)=(1) is not present in table "bar"
```

How come `bar_id` is not present in the table? I thought, I can just retry after `db.session.rollback()` and the `bar_id=bar.id` should still be valid.

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy plugin in a Flask application and the aforementioned code is in a request function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I need to use `db.session.savepoint()` so it doesn't rollback *all* previous inserts.

After inserting `bar = Bar()` followed by `db.session.flush()`, I need to create a savepoint.

Full working code here:

```py
max_retries=3
bar = Bar()
db.session.add(bar)
db.session.flush()
db.session.savepoint() # <-- Add this line
while True:
    try:
        obj = Foo(foo=get_unique_id(n=6), bar_id=bar.id)
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.flush()
    except IntegrityError:
        db.session.rollback()
        max_retries -= 1
        if max_retries < 1:
            raise
    else:
        break
db.session.commit()
```